# Remove many-to-many with additional field

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have 2 entities that have n-n relationship. The reference entity has some additional fields so I have to change the relationship between 3 entities like this.

```
User --(1-n)-- UserAddress --(n-1)-- Address
```

In User entity I have a mapping to UserAddress:

```
<one-to-many target-entity="UserAddress" mapped-by="user" field="addresses">
   <cascade>
     <cascade-all/>
    </cascade>
</one-to-many>
```

My User Entity:

```
protected $addresses;

public function addAddress(UserAddress $address)
{
    $this->addresses[] = $address;

    return $this;
}

public function removeAddress(UserAddress $address)
{
    $this->addresses->removeElement($address);
}

public function getAddresses()
{
    return $this->addresses;
}

public function __construct()
{
    $this->addresses = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

When I try to remove an address from User addresses collection by **$user->removeAddress($address)**, Recheck $addresses array and that address have been removed. But in the database it still exist. I expect to remove 2 field in the database, one in UserAddress table and one in Address. how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

`$user->removeAddress($address)` removes only element from ArrayCollection.

After removing from ArrayCollection you must persist your entity in EntityManager and then flush your EntityManager. And then you can see some changes in your database.

After that operation you can see that record from UserAddress table has been removed. To remove record from Address you must declare your foreign_key linked to Address table with cascade ORM rule. You make one cascade rule (User -> UserAddress) but now you need one more (UserAddress -> Address)

Answer (score 0):

You could define cascade on the field in the class UserAddress:

```
/** @OneToMany(targetEntity="Address", mappedBy="address", cascade={"remove"}) */
protected $addresses;
```

For more information read [this](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/working-with-associations.html).

Comment: is simple cascade={"remove"} on both not enough?